# How to make WPF projects build on run?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

In Visual Studio 2012 I want my projects to build on run. Typically I'd do this via

Options> Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > Always build when project is out of date.

For all my other solutions Winforms, MVC, class libraries, etc this happens but not with WPF projects.
How can I make this the default behaviour in WPF?

Comment: have you checked that in your solution properties -> Configuration Properties the "Build" column is checked for your WPF project?

Comment: Grrrr. That is the answer. Newly added projects don't build by    default?

Comment: Weird, all mine are set to Build by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to check that in your solution properties -> Configuration Properties the "Build" column is checked for your WPF project!